# Chromium renames files whose names have diacritics to “download (n)”

Tags: google-chrome, locale, chromium

When I try to download files whose names contain diactrics, Chromium saves them as “download,” “download (1),” “download (2)” and so forth, and I can’t figure out why.

I am using Chromium Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit).

My locale variables are:

```
% locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Screenshot of Chromium’s downloads tab:

[image: Screenshot of Chromium’s downloads tab]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the same problem in Ubuntu 16.04 but wasn't able to do so. May be because i tried downloading a different language (chinese):
[chinese_filename_while_downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KCWd.png).
This is the image of my `locale`  [locale_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M99DD.png)
I would like to say that the issue/problem is not with chromium instead with the values in `locale`.
There is an issue registered for this in the chromium.org. Here is the link: [bug_registered](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1148) . Please have a look, the issue looks the same but for a different language.  Did you try to replicate the issue with other browsers or is it specific with this(chromium) browser only?

Note: I have tried the issue using google chrome Version 75.0.3770.142.